# Ubuntu 16.04Install: Flashing Icons

Tags: nvidia

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a dual-boot machine (with Windows 10). There were no warnings or errors. However, when I boot the machine, it gets to the pinkish/purple-ish Ubuntu default background, but everything else is empty.  No icons, or panels.

If I right click, I get a menu for creating Folders, or documents, or launching terminals, but that menu is flashing on and off about once per second.  If I create a folder, then that folder icon appears on the desktop, but it is flashing on and off about once per second

What is going on? The PC is an Intel I7 6800K, and the video card is Nvidia GTX 970.